# Counterexamples in Analysis error: everywhere continuous, nowhere differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

The following is the argument for an everywhere continuous, nowhere differentiable function in the book *Counterexamples in Analysis* by Gelbaum and Olmsted.

> Let $f_1(x) := |x|$ for $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and extend to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by periodic continuation. For $n > 1$, define $f_n = 4^{-n+1} f_1(4^{n-1}x)$. Define $f$ by
>   $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f_1(4^{n-1}x)}{4^{n-1}}$$
>   ...let $a$ be an arbitrary real number, and for any positive integer $n$, choose $h_n$ to be either $4^{-n-1}$ or $-4^{-n-1}$ so that $|f_n(a + h_n) - f_n(a)| = |h_n|$. Then $|f_m(a + h_n) - f_m(a)|$ has this same value $|h_n|$ for all $m \leq n$, and vanishes for $m > n$. Hence the difference quotient $(f(a + h_n) - f(a))/h_n$ is an integer that is even if $n$ is even and odd if $n$ is odd. It follows that 
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a + h_n) - f(a)}{h_n}$$
>   cannot exist, and therefore that $f'(a)$ cannot exist as a finite limit.

First, I think that we must choose $h_n = \pm 4^n$, instead of $\pm 4^{n-1}$, to be able to guarantee that $|f_n(a + h_n) - f_n(a)| = |h_n|$ for some choice of sign.

Secondly, I don't buy the statement

> Hence the difference quotient $(f(a + h_n) - f(a))/h_n$ is an integer that is even if $n$ is even and odd if $n$ is odd"

Abbot's Analysis book has a similar argument claiming that at $0$, the value of difference quotient with difference $h_n$ is $n$.

In this case, for the difference quotient to be equal to $n$ and hence share the same parity, I believe the difference quotients (which are $\pm 1$) for each $f_n$ must have the same sign, and this is not necessarily true for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: Spivak has a detailed proof of this. And his argument is the same.

Comment: Just so you know, math.se is not just for answering one person's question. Ideally, if in the future someone else has the same question, they would be able to search the archives of this forum and find an answer. I don't know what your question was, but it's advised to keep it posted, even if the answer turned out to be obvious.

Comment: Edit: restored. I suppose I'll answer my own question in the comments.

Comment: @user3821234: No, please add an actual answer and tick that. Others might have the same questions (no matter how silly you think it is). btw, your question writing skills are exemplary! (One more reason to have this question sticking around :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to justify the original exponent, if my arithmetic is correct. Choose $x$ with $|x| = 4^{-(n+1)}$, and so that there is no critical point of $f_n$ between $a$ and $a+x$. We can do this because the critical points of $f_n$ are spaced 
$$(1/2)\cdot 4^{-(n-1)} > (1/4)\cdot 4^{-n+1} = 4^{-n}> 2\cdot4^{-n-1} = 2|x|.$$

Then we have
$$
\begin{split}
|f_n(a + x) - f_n(a)| & = |4^{-n+1} f_1(4^{n-1}(x))| \\
&= 4^{-n+1}f_1(|4^{n-1}4^{-(n+1)}|)
= 4^{-n+1}f_1(4^{-2})\\
& = 4^{-n+1}4^{-2}\\
& = 4^{-n-1}  \\
& = |x|
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 3):

For the parity argument, I looked into Spivak's calculus book p. 501 as suggested by Pedro.
The fact that the difference quotient and $n$ have the same parity reduces to the fact that every time $\pm 1$ is added, the parity is changed. Since the difference quotient is the sum of $\pm 1$, taken $n$ times, it has the same parity as $n$.